# Wastebasket not enabled for NFS mounted folders

Tags: mount, fstab, nfs, trash

I have been unable to find a relevant answer to this problem, although it's the sort of thing that is commonly reported on the web.

I recently migrated my existing HDD drives to a new Synology NAS after the old one died, which is when my troubles started.

I have always mounted a number of folders from the NAS on my Ubuntu PC using NFS, so that I can create "backup" copies of important files on the server. Before my old NAS died I used FreeFileSync to mirror files and folders from Ubuntu to the NFS-mounted NAS folders, and this worked fine. Since the migration I have been unable to do this because the NFS-mounted folders apparently cannot see a trash/rubbish bin/wastebasket to move the updated or deleted files to. I get the dreaded "Unable to find or create Rubbish Bin directory... " message. I'm fairly sure that I need to create an appropriate ".Trash" folder with its usual subfolders in the Synology Shared Folders, but I can't discover how to do it.

I mount the NAS folders (successfully) using /etc/fstab, e.g.

```
192.xxx.x.xxx:/volume1/videos /media/NAS/NAS\040videos nfs timeo=200,fg
```

During the migration of my HDD drives I did have problems with some presumably pre-existing .Trash folders turning up in my Ubuntu wastebasket as links which meant that I had to delete stuff from the NAS before I could empty the wastebasket. "Something" obviously went wrong during the migration but I can't find what, or how to fix it.

I can delete files manually from the mounted folders, and I can recycle files from the NAS folders if I login to the to NAS.

Comment: What version of Ubuntu?

Comment: Listing given by lsb_release -a:
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description: Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS
Release: 20.04
Codename: focal

Comment: First update you should be on 20.04.3

Comment: OK, done that. For some reason Ubuntu hadn't informed me about updates (possibly because I asked it not to...).

Comment: I have since tried putting a .Trash-1000 folder in the /media mount point (1000 is me, another user is 1001), but without effect. Given that all this used to work seamlessly a few weeks ago, I don't actually think that this level of tinkering should be required, and that it is all somehow to do with NFS permissions in /etc/fstab, or else permissions on the NAS folders. But so far I can't see it.

Comment: I've had to give up on this. for example, I'm fairly confident now that using UID/GID does not work for NFS mounted folders. Similarly, creatiing .Trash-type folders on mounted folders also does not work. Not sure how this could have worked before, but I have now simply set FreeFileSync to delete files that have to be overwritten (updated) and that works fine. I have also of necessity restricted update options to Mirror from Linux to Synology NAS (L to R) so as not to risk losing important data. This topic is therefore CLOSED as far as I am concerned.